# Get Google Search Images using php

Tags: php, curl, google-image-search

Search on Google images with car keyword & get car images.

[image]

I found two links to implement like this,

1. [PHP class to retrieve multiple images from Google using curl multi
   handler](http://webcodingeasy.com/PHP-classes/PHP-class-to-retrieve-multiple-images-from-Google-using-curl-multi-handler)
2. [Google image API using cURL](http://webcodingeasy.com/PHP-API039s/Google-image-API-using-cURL)

implement also but it gave 4 random images not more than that.
[image][image][image][image]

**Question:** How to get car images in PHP using keyword i want to implement like we search on Google?

Any suggestion will be appreciated!!!

Comment: The link you posted in your question has a note at the bottom stating that if you want more than 4 images try this: http://webcodingeasy.com/PHP-classes/PHP-class-to-retrieve-multiple-images-from-Google-using-curl-multi-handler

Comment: @shannonman yes when i open this link my first link open & give same results & i also change $count value but get same.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [PHP Simple HTML DOM library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for this:

```
<?php
    include "simple_html_dom.php";
    $search_query = "ENTER YOUR SEARCH QUERY HERE";
    $search_query = urlencode( $search_query );
    $html = file_get_html( "https://www.google.com/search?q=$search_query&tbm=isch" );
    $image_container = $html->find('div#rcnt', 0);
    $images = $image_container->find('img');
    $image_count = 10; //Enter the amount of images to be shown
    $i = 0;
    foreach($images as $image){
        if($i == $image_count) break;
        $i++;
        // DO with the image whatever you want here (the image element is '$image'):
        echo $image;
    }
```

This will print a specific number of images (number is set in '$image_count').

For more information on the PHP Simple HTML DOM library [click here.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: you forgot $i++ in the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

i am not very much sure about this  ,but still google gives a nice documentation about this.

```
 $url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?" .
   "v=1.0&q=barack%20obama&userip=INSERT-USER-IP";   
// sendRequest
// note how referer is set manually
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, /* Enter the URL of your site here */);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// now, process the JSON string
$json = json_decode($body);
// now have some fun with the results...
```

this is from the official Google's developer guide regarding image searching.
for more reference you can have a reference of the same here.

```
 https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide#json_snippets_php
```

in $url you must set the search keywords.

Comment: The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011.